# docker dropping traffic from same subnet

Tags: docker, ubuntu, iptables

I'm try to resolve/investigate the reason why I can't reach the container (http://10.0.3.2:9200) from a VM/host 10.0.3.3. I did confirm that the incoming packet reaches the host 10.0.3.2 but are not forwarded to docker 0. If I do the same thing from another VM/host (10.0.4.35) it works.

I posted the same thing on docker forum but I didn't get any response so far, so I'm taking my chance here.

I suspect that the packet that comes from 10.0.3.3 are never forwarded to docker0 bridge but I don't know the reason.

This is the diagram of the host/network:
[Diagram of interconnection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe9mE.png)

and this all what I have:

OS version:

```
Linux elk 5.4.0-77-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 02:35:03 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Docker Version:

```
Client:
 Version:           20.10.2
Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.8
```

connectivity test from VM2 → VM3:

```
curl http://10.0.3.2:9200
{
 "name" : "elk",
 "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
 "cluster_uuid" : "ElvQdiCURke3peA7scMvYw",
 "version" : {
   "number" : "7.13.2",
   "build_flavor" : "default",
   "build_type" : "tar",
   "build_hash" : "4d960a0733be83dd2543ca018aa4ddc42e956800",
   "build_date" : "2021-06-10T21:01:55.251515791Z",
   "build_snapshot" : false,
   "lucene_version" : "8.8.2",
   "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
   "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
 },
 "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

connectivity test from VM1 → VM3:

```
ping 10.0.3.2
PING 10.0.3.2 (10.0.3.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 10.0.3.2 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 6.612/8.821/13.655/2.839 ms

curl http://10.0.3.2:9200
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 10.0.3.2 port 9200: Connection timed out
```

iptables trace shows these:

When it works:

```
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:3 IN=ens19 OUT= MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=10.0.3.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=48299 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993933 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AD52228100000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=ens19 OUT= MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=10.0.3.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=48299 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993933 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AD52228100000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: nat:PREROUTING:rule:1 IN=ens19 OUT= MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=10.0.3.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=48299 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993933 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AD52228100000000001030307) 
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: nat:DOCKER:rule:2 IN=ens19 OUT= MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=10.0.3.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=48299 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993933 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AD52228100000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: mangle:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48299 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993933 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AD52228100000000001030307) 
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:FORWARD:rule:1 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48299 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993933 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AD52228100000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:DOCKER-USER:return:2 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48299 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993933 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AD52228100000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:FORWARD:rule:2 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48299 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993933 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AD52228100000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1:return:2 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48299 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993933 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AD52228100000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:FORWARD:rule:4 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48299 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993933 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AD52228100000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:DOCKER:rule:1 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48299 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993933 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AD52228100000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: security:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48299 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993933 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AD52228100000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: mangle:POSTROUTING:policy:1 IN= OUT=docker0 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48299 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993933 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AD52228100000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: nat:POSTROUTING:policy:5 IN= OUT=docker0 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48299 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993933 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AD52228100000000001030307) 

Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:3 IN=ens19 OUT= MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=10.0.3.2 LEN=129 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=48301 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=ens19 OUT= MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=10.0.3.2 LEN=129 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=48301 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:3 IN=ens19 OUT= MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=10.0.3.2 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=48300 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB) 
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=ens19 OUT= MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=10.0.3.2 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=48300 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: mangle:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=129 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48301 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB) 
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:FORWARD:rule:1 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=129 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48301 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:DOCKER-USER:return:2 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=129 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48301 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:FORWARD:rule:2 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=129 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48301 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1:return:2 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=129 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48301 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:FORWARD:rule:3 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=129 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48301 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: security:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=129 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48301 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: mangle:POSTROUTING:policy:1 IN= OUT=docker0 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=129 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48301 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: mangle:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48300 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:FORWARD:rule:1 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48300 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:DOCKER-USER:return:2 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48300 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:FORWARD:rule:2 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48300 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1:return:2 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48300 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:FORWARD:rule:3 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48300 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: security:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=ens19 OUT=docker0 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48300 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB) 
Jul 29 22:12:21 elk kernel: TRACE: mangle:POSTROUTING:policy:1 IN= OUT=docker0 SRC=10.0.4.35 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=48300 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40114 DPT=9200 SEQ=4278993934 ACK=696567754 WINDOW=502 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 OPT (0101080AD522281FD7D3F4AB)
```

When it doesn’t work:

```
Jul 29 22:09:50 elk kernel: TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:3 IN=ens19 OUT= MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=10.0.3.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=15697 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB6757E150000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:09:50 elk kernel: TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=ens19 OUT= MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=10.0.3.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=15697 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB6757E150000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:09:50 elk kernel: TRACE: nat:PREROUTING:rule:1 IN=ens19 OUT= MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=10.0.3.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=15697 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB6757E150000000001030307) 
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Jul 29 22:09:50 elk kernel: TRACE: nat:DOCKER:rule:2 IN=ens19 OUT= MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=10.0.3.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=15697 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB6757E150000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:09:50 elk kernel: TRACE: mangle:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=ens19 OUT=ens19 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=15697 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB6757E150000000001030307) 
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Jul 29 22:09:50 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:FORWARD:rule:1 IN=ens19 OUT=ens19 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=15697 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB6757E150000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:09:50 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:DOCKER-USER:rule:1 IN=ens19 OUT=ens19 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=15697 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB6757E150000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:09:50 elk kernel: TRACE: security:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=ens19 OUT=ens19 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:44:d3:ca:5c:54:f4:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=15697 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB6757E150000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:09:50 elk kernel: TRACE: mangle:POSTROUTING:policy:1 IN= OUT=ens19 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=15697 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB6757E150000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:09:50 elk kernel: TRACE: nat:POSTROUTING:policy:5 IN= OUT=ens19 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=15697 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB6757E150000000001030307) 

Jul 29 22:09:51 elk kernel: TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:3 IN=ens19 OUT= MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:b6:84:98:5c:a0:60:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=10.0.3.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=15698 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB67582180000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:09:51 elk kernel: TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=ens19 OUT= MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:b6:84:98:5c:a0:60:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=10.0.3.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=15698 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB67582180000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:09:51 elk kernel: TRACE: mangle:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=ens19 OUT=ens19 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:b6:84:98:5c:a0:60:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=15698 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB67582180000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:09:51 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:FORWARD:rule:1 IN=ens19 OUT=ens19 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:b6:84:98:5c:a0:60:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=15698 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB67582180000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:09:51 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:DOCKER-USER:rule:1 IN=ens19 OUT=ens19 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:b6:84:98:5c:a0:60:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=15698 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB67582180000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:09:51 elk kernel: TRACE: security:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=ens19 OUT=ens19 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:b6:84:98:5c:a0:60:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=15698 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB67582180000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:09:51 elk kernel: TRACE: mangle:POSTROUTING:policy:1 IN= OUT=ens19 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=15698 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB67582180000000001030307) 

Jul 29 22:09:53 elk kernel: TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:3 IN=ens19 OUT= MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:b6:84:98:5c:a0:60:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=10.0.3.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=15699 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB67589F80000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:09:53 elk kernel: TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=ens19 OUT= MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:b6:84:98:5c:a0:60:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=10.0.3.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=15699 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB67589F80000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:09:53 elk kernel: TRACE: mangle:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=ens19 OUT=ens19 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:b6:84:98:5c:a0:60:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=15699 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB67589F80000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:09:53 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:FORWARD:rule:1 IN=ens19 OUT=ens19 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:b6:84:98:5c:a0:60:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=15699 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB67589F80000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:09:53 elk kernel: TRACE: filter:DOCKER-USER:rule:1 IN=ens19 OUT=ens19 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:b6:84:98:5c:a0:60:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=15699 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB67589F80000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:09:53 elk kernel: TRACE: security:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=ens19 OUT=ens19 MAC=ee:95:39:76:c7:f9:b6:84:98:5c:a0:60:08:00 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=15699 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB67589F80000000001030307) 
Jul 29 22:09:53 elk kernel: TRACE: mangle:POSTROUTING:policy:1 IN= OUT=ens19 SRC=10.0.3.3 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=15699 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34200 DPT=9200 SEQ=2207217953 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080AB67589F80000000001030307)
```

This is configuration of VM3/host3:

```
2: ens19: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
   link/ether ee:95:39:76:c7:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   inet 10.0.3.2/24 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global ens19
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet6 fe80::ec95:39ff:fe76:c7f9/64 scope link 
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
   link/ether 02:42:29:0f:2c:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet6 fe80::42:29ff:fe0f:2c8b/64 scope link 
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: veth1650f38@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
   link/ether 3e:dc:8c:f7:6b:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
   inet6 fe80::3cdc:8cff:fef7:6b13/64 scope link 
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

docker bridge details:

```
   {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "cd2d8dde2f9c11980926f53175b738696d792db1097c2db8697e7a438ab4eee2",
        "Created": "2021-07-21T03:00:01.289033231Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "db9f7e1f765b7b05fd967d722ac05c41551aa2c42fa224b3bd4270f1667e9c59": {
                "Name": "sam_elk_1",
                "EndpointID": "0db88ed751b47ac6c214f5423da8769be8b496779bb685695bb97b2cb407eae3",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
```

routes on host3/VM3:

```
default via 10.0.3.1 dev ens19 proto static 
10.0.3.0/24 dev ens19 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.2 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
```

the content of iptables :

```
################################################################################
iptables:filter table:
################################################################################
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DOCKER-USER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2    DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4    DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
5    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
6    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:9200


Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2    RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2    RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.0.3.0/24          0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9200
2    RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
################################################################################
iptables:nat table:
################################################################################
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
2    MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:9200


Chain DOCKER (2 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2    DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9200 to:172.17.0.2:9200
################################################################################
iptables:mangle & security tables: empty, default accept
################################################################################
################################################################################
iptables:raw table:
################################################################################
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    TRACE      tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.0.3.2             tcp dpt:9200
2    TRACE      tcp  --  10.0.3.2             0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:9200

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    TRACE      tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.0.3.2             tcp dpt:9200
2    TRACE      tcp  --  10.0.3.2             0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:9200
```